How was Google able to find out my subdomain when it wasn't linked from anywhere
I created a subdomain xyz.domain.com literally like yesterday. I'm using Dreamhost VPS and CloudFlare.
Today was showing up in Google index. The subdomain is literally a coming soon page. It was not linked from anywhere. No GSC no nothing.
How was Google able to find out this subdomain? Is Chrome monitoring all the URLs I visit? Is Dreamhost or CloudFlare publicly listing or "Sharing" API data of all domains with Google?
Does Google have a special technology to scan a domain name for all the cnames?
Please help me solve this mystery.

This one puzzled me to a while back - Most likely its being found as a result of the SSL certificate generation - Cert Transparency logs (see https://letsencrypt.org/docs/ct-logs/ for example) are public knowledge and  I am pretty sure Google monitors these and adds new sites shortly after the cert is (created and) logged.

That could be it, but why is Google indexing empty pages, when it is about the so-called "quality content" for them. Shouldn't only quality pages be indexed? Like why is it in a hurry to index domain parking pages.

Short answer is "don't know - ask Google".   I expect any answer would be speculation and would boil down to Google likes to know when sites are created so it can be comprehensive.   Also, the longer a site exists the more credibility Google gives it - so Google possibly also uses the intiial hit as a baseline?   I also expect that to some extent the left hand does not know what the right hand is doing - ie it splits up the indexing across many servers, and only later on consolidates and strips what it thinks is not quality content out its servers later.    Again, all this is speculation.

So, how did Google find your subdomain so quickly? It might seem mysterious, but there are actually a few ways this could have happened.
One common reason is SSL certificate transparency logs. When you create a subdomain and secure it with SSL (like through Let's Encrypt), the certificate details get logged publicly, and Google monitors these logs. As soon as your SSL certificate is issued and listed, Google can discover the new subdomain and index it, even if it's not linked anywhere.
It’s also possible that Googlebot stumbled upon the subdomain through a shared IP address or from other sites hosted on the same server. Plus, if someone visited the subdomain using Chrome, data might be sent back to Google, contributing to its discovery. But no, Chrome isn’t spying on all URLs you visit, and Dreamhost or CloudFlare aren’t just sharing your data with Google either. It's more about how Google's bots are incredibly efficient at picking up on changes across the web.
